# Schema tables in MSSQL 2008 and Cakephp 2.0

Tags: sql-server-2008, cakephp-2.0

Not able to access schema tables MSSQL 2008 in Cakephp 2.0.How can i do this ? Do i need to change any thing in models or somewhere else to access particular Schema Tables ?

Please Help Me..

Answer (score 0):

in model with :

```
$this->schema();
```

Comment: i have a model named 'user' which represents a table named 'users' which is in the schema named 'Public'. How should i refer this table 'Public.users' in cake php ?